KeyError: 'model' For custom yolov8 model
I keep getting this error,
`File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\models\yolo\model.py", line 23, in __init__
    super().__init__(model=model, task=task, verbose=verbose)
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 152, in __init__
    self._load(model, task=task)
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 241, in _load
    self.model, self.ckpt = attempt_load_one_weight(weights)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\nn\tasks.py", line 813, in attempt_load_one_weight
    model = (ckpt.get("ema") or ckpt["model"]).to(device).float()  # FP32 model
                                ~~~~^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'model'`

Here is my code:

from ultralytics import YOLO

model= YOLO('model.pt')

results = model(source=0, show= True, conf=0.5, save= True)

I tried to retrain the model
I tried downloading other pretrained models etc.

how did you train your model (model.pt)??
you can use netron.app to check if the model is not corrupted
